# Touches not going through text view

Tags: ios, xcode

Sorry for a newbie question but my touches are not going through the text view.

I have a cell created from XIB with such elements: image view, label and a text view. So when I'm tapping wherever except the text view `didSelectCell:` is called. In other way - not.

Please suggest how to debug or what could be the reason?

Comment: If you are using `UITextView` in none-editable mode than just set `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO`.

Comment: You made my day m8. Many thanks! If you make it an answer not comment - I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Moved from comments.*

If you are using `UITextView` in none-editable mode than just set `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO`.